# Use the numbers from Response.Json() string and pass it as parameters to get requests and loop append the results in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, rest

I am using the below code to fetch results from rest api. Looping the results and appending the same.

```
mylog = []
offset = 0
limit = 50

while True:    
    url = f"https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_nrql_conditions.json?offset={offset}&limit={limit}"
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    data = response.json()
    if len(data['data']) == 0:
        break    
    mylog.extend(data['data'])    
    offset = offset + 50
```

But now I have a JSON string as below. I want to use the ID number from the below to pass it as parameter to the above URL. Parameter should be poilicy_id and the value should be the number from the JSON strings as below.

Get the result for first Policy ID and append it one by one.

Please help me to code this as I am new to Python.

```
{
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": 1119732,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION_AND_TARGET",
      "name": "Alert 1",
      "created_at": 1605003072469,
      "updated_at": 1673391349002
    },
    {
      "id": 1133740,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION",
      "name": "Alert 2",
      "created_at": 1605780951866,
      "updated_at": 1673391348520
    },
    {
      "id": 1136308,
      "incident_preference": "PER_CONDITION",
      "name": "Alert 3",
      "created_at": 1605886254921,
      "updated_at": 1673391349028
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your key value pairs in a list, I would begin by extracting it so you can iterate over it:

```
y = list(data.values())
y = y[0]
```

you can then do the following:

```
url1 = "https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_nrql_conditions.json"
newdict = {}
for i in range(len(y)):
    newdict.update(y[i])
    newurl=url1+f"policy_id={newdict['id']}"
    # Then do what you need to with url.
```